# Delphi debugger crash (OpenDialog + compressed exe)

Tags: delphi, debugging, topendialog, upx

A few days ago I encountered a strange bug

Whenever my program (under debugging) tries to open a savedialog Delphi 2007 IDE crashes with an external exception. I narrowed it down to any folder containing an exe compressed by upx located.

I.e. if all exe's in a folder are normal/uncompressed then all is good. But if one of exe files has been compressed with upx then IDE crashes when opendialog tries to open that folder.

I suspect that Windows shell loads the exe module (e.g. to display its icon) and IDE notices that and tries to load debugging info for that exe and crashed at that point.

Any idea on how to resolve this? My test program attached

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    procedure FormClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveDialog1.Execute()
end;

end.
```

UPDATE: Added a screenshot with IDE stack trace
[image]

Comment: It will likely be due to a shell extension bringing the house down. Try disabling extensions until you work out which one is to blame.

Comment: You could always enable the `ofOldStyleDialog` flag in the `Options` property. The dialog will likely look terrible on modern Windows machines, but it won't host an instance of Explorer and thus won't load any Shell Extensions.

Comment: David, this is clean Win10 install. 
Remy, Tried that, but it still crashed

Comment: You might want to post the call stack for when this happens.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko Are you using any IDE add-ons?  Cn-Pack, G-Experts, IDE Fix packs, etc?  Or is this a clean D2k7 install?

Comment: 500, Added a screenshot. I hope I made it clear that this is IDE that crashes, not my program.
J, No IDE add-ons. There was JCL but I uninstalled it - no change.

Comment: Maybe check out which shell extensions you're using, and try disabling some. http://superuser.com/questions/286000/how-to-list-explorer-extensions-and-disable-them

Comment: By the way, what happens when you run your application without the debugger?

Comment: Wouter. obviously, without debugger all is well